# How to fix a Non-compliant Android app that uses AMAP SDK

Tags: android

We are maintaining an Android application that uses the **AMAP SDK**. We received an email in which Google warn us that our application will be removed because the **AMAP SDK** violates the policy: **THE MALICIOUS BEHAVIOR POLICY**(The SDK is executing downloadable code). 
Do you know what can be done in this situation? Is there someone that faced this issue with the **AMAP SDK**  and found a solution?

Thank you!